# "Sarei potuta essere arrivata prima" vs. "Sarei potuta arrivare prima"

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense

Supponiamo io abbia partecipato ad una gara e, per un evento sfortunato ed evitabile, sono arrivata seconda.

Come potrei grammaticalmente esprimere ciò? con a) o con b)?

> a) Sarei potuta essere arrivata prima.
>
> b) Sarei potuta arrivare prima.

a) e b) sembrano entrambe grammaticalmente corrette, ma è possibile che non ci sia una qualche differenza di significato?

Chiedo perché non mi capacito di non riuscire a pensarne neanche una.

Comment: E perché no allora "avrei potuto aver potuto arrivare prima"? (retorica)

Comment: @ElberichSchneider se si può dire "posso essere arrivato" (e si può), in via del tutto teorica, mettendo il verbo servile al passato prossimo, risulterebbe "sono potuto essere arrivato" (o forse "ho potuto essere arrivato", non sono sicuro né dell'ausiliare né che la frase sia valida). Comunque certamente in pratica nessuno la userebbe.

Comment: Bilanciato downvote non necessario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L’espressione del passato, nel caso in esame, è affidata soltanto al verbo servile. Perciò l’unica frase corretta è «Sarei potuta arrivare prima». La frase «*Sarei potuta essere arrivata prima» è agrammaticale.

Quanto all’ausiliare, se è vero che la norma prevede che il verbo servile (*potere*, *dovere*, *volere*) prenda l’ausiliare del verbo retto, per cui si dice «Sarei potuto arrivare» come si dice «Sono arrivato», è altrettanto vero che non è scorretto scrivere «*Avrei* potuto arrivare», anche se certamente è meno consigliabile sia perché minoritario nell’uso e, generalmente, ritenuto (a torto) meno corretto, sia per il rispetto della tradizione letteraria (cfr. Pietro Bembo, *Prose della volgar lingua*, Libro III, XLI).

A tale riguardo, mette conto riportare ciò che scrive Giuseppe Patota in Luca Serianni, *Italiano*, Milano: «Garzanti», 2000, s.v. «Ausiliari, verbi» (sezione «Glossario e dubbi linguistici»):

> Se l’infinito è un verbo intransitivo, il verbo reggente può costruirsi anche con *avere* (*ho dovuto uscire*)[.]

I verbi servili che reggono il verbo *essere* prendono invece di norma sempre l’ausiliare *avere*: es. ***avrei*** potuto essere un pilota, ***ha*** dovuto essere esaminato, ecc.

Tuttavia, anche con *essere* e un verbo servile si può avere l’ausiliare *essere*, in un caso: quando il verbo *essere* retto da *potere*, *volere*, *dovere* ha un pieno valore verbale, e non è né copula né ausiliare del passivo. Si confrontino questi due esempi boccacciani:

> Portatelo in pace, che quello che stanotte non **è potuto essere** sarà
>   un’altra volta. [VIII giornata, novella VII]
>
> Se io non **avessi voluto essere al mondo**, io mi sarei fatta monaca […].
>   [V giornata, novella X]

Nel primo esempio, *essere* vale ‹avvenire, accadere› (cfr. *Vocabolario Treccani*, «[Essere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/essere1/)», accezione 3e); nel secondo è un verbo funzionale e, piú precisamente, concorre alla formazione del predicato nominale con «al mondo».

Comment: Giustissimo, e il glossario condensa quello che dice il testo principale nel cap. XI. In particolare, di servili + intransitivi si parla nel par. XI.38, con l'ulteriore esempio «non aveva più potuto ripartire» (da *Cristo si è fermato a Eboli* di Carlo Levi).

Comment: Grazie mille della precisazione. Sebbene non sia sbagliato usare _sempre_ l’ausiliare _avere_ (con un’eccezione, cioè quando si ha un verbo pronominale col pronome in posizione proclitica), questo costrutto alternativo è spesso oggetto di proscrizione. Ricordo a questo riguardo la pubblicità di un’agenzia di scommesse, nel quale uno dei protagonisti sottolineava la scelta dell’ausiliare in una frase come «Non ha potuto venire».

Comment: Giusto per non appropriarmi di un’intuizione non mia, preciso che la seconda parte della risposta, quella che riguarda l’uso dell’ausiliare coi verbi servili che reggono _essere_, l’ho presa da quest’intervento: http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?p=47012#47012.

Comment: Questa è una risposta, non sarebbe potuta essere migliore!

Answer (score 1):

> - L’uso dell’ausiliare con i verbi servili in italiano non risponde ad un’unica norma. Per quanto riguarda la circostanza in cui dopo il verbo servile (dovere, potere, volere) ci sia il verbo essere, **la norma specifica stabilisce che l’ausiliare è il verbo avere.** Dunque diremo e scriveremo: avrei dovuto essere, hanno potuto essere, aveva voluto essere ecc.
> - Questo perchè con i verbi servili volere, potere e dovere per formare i tempi composti bisogna usare l'ausiliare del verbo successivo, a eccezione del verbo essere che vuole come ausiliare avere!

Ne segue che:

> - *Sarei potuta arrivare prima*, è  la frase corretta ( essere si coniuga con arrivare).

La frase al punto a) è completamente sgrammaticata.

Comment: Che c'entra? '*avrei dovuto essere* più bella di te' è corretta perché qui dopo il servile c'è realmente il verbo *essere*, ma in '*sarei potuta essere arrivata* prima' non c'è il verbo *essere* ma il verbo *arrivare* — e ciò essendo 'essere arrivata' l'infinito passato del verbo arrivare → -1

Comment: *Sarei potuta essere arrivata* ... Non è' una frase corretta, mi spiace. devi dire: *Sarei potuta arrivare!*