# È corretto usare 'avrebbe dovuto finire'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, foreign-words

Recentemente su un noto quotidiano online ho trovato il seguente titolo "ecco come avrebbe dovuto finire". Io ho pensato fosse un grave errore grammaticale tant'è che dopo pochi minuti il titolo è stato cambiato. Discutendo con un collega però è nato il dubbio che fosse corretta anche la forma con il verbo avere. Chi ha ragione?

Comment: Related http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/sarei-potuta-essere-arrivata-prima-vs-sarei-potuta-arrivare-prima

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per me hai ragione tu. Per quanto ne so, salvo eccezioni, per i verbi modali l'ausiliare è quello del verbo che segue. In questo caso `finire` è intransitivo e vuole essere, quindi la forma corretta è `ecco come sarebbe dovuto finire`.

C'è anche la faccia transitiva di finire (`finire il compito`) e `avrebbe dovuto finire il compito` (dove `il compito` è complemento oggetto e c'è un misterioso soggetto sottinteso) va bene. Quindi se prendi la stringa `ecco come avrebbe dovuto finire` avulsa da ogni contesto, effettivamente il tuo collega ha ragione.

Comment: Ciao, grazie della risposta. Faccio una precisazione sul contesto nel quale è inserita quella frase; si parla del vero finale di una storia raccontata in una canzone. Quindi immagina il titolo come "la vera storia della canzone xxxxx, ecco come avrebbe dovuto finire". A me sembra un errore. Che ne dici?

Comment: Se il soggetto è la canzone confermo che quella forma è sbagliata e quella giusta è `ecco come sarebbe dovuta finire`. Aggiungo che nel parlato di tutti i giorni violerei scientemente le regole e userei un piattissimo indicativo imperfetto.

Answer (score 3):

Per quanto ne so io, i verbi servili (come erano noti i verbi modali nelle "vecchie" grammatiche) possono utilizzare l'ausiliare avere pure con i verbi intransitivi, anche se di preferenza si usa l'ausiliare del verbo principale.

Cito dalla mia grammatica "Dardano-Trifone, *La Lingua Italiana*, 1985, Zanichelli", sezione **7.9 VERBI SERVILI E VERBI FRASEOLOGICI**, pag.220:

> **Verbi servili**
>
> Sono *dovere*, *potere*, *volere*; [...]
>
> A sottolineare lo stretto legame tra il verbo servile ed il verbo che lo segue, il primo ha per lo più l'ausiliare del secondo: [...]
>
> Ma è frequente trovare i verbi servili con l'ausiliare *avere*, anche quando il verbo che reggono richiede l'ausiliare *essere*: *sono tornato* / *ho dovuto (potuto, voluto) tornare*. In particolare, i verbi servili hanno l'ausiliare *avere* quando sono seguiti dal verbo *essere*:
> *ho dovuto (potuto, voluto) essere magnanimo*.

Quindi "Ecco come avrebbe dovuto finire" è perfettamente accettabile, anche se "Ecco come sarebbe dovuto finire" rispecchia un uso più comune dell'ausiliare.

Aggiungo inoltre una [fonte dal sito dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/ausiliare-verbi-servili), che conferma quanto sopra.